# visual studion debug web server looking in wrong path for web.config

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, iis

I recently changed a drive letter from F: to D:.  As it happens it contains my "My Documents folder.

Now when I try to run a web app in the debugger in visual studio, I get (in the browser):

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>   The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

The path it is looking for is still referencing the F: drive:

> \?\F:\users\myname\My Documents\My Web
>   Sites\Trac.Application-Site(2)\web.config

Where is this path set?  Why did it not pick up on the fact that my "my documents" folder is now on the D: drive? (I have updated the location of my documents to point to the correct location)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I think you have already found solution for this old problem. Maybe my answer can help others.

In your web application project Right-click to **Name in Solution Explorer**. Then select **Project Properties**. On the **Web Tab** click the button which is named **"Create Virtual Directory"**.

We accrossed this problem when we pushed the project to TFS.